# How to handle third party SSO provider (OAuth implementation) in WSO2 to control access of API exposed based on roles

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I have to implement SSO in my project using third party OAuth service provider. External user will consume APIs which are exposed in WSO2. Third party service provider will provide OAuth token based on token request.

I have to control user access based on roles using OAuth token. Please suggest your ideas if anyone came across this scenario.

Comment: Are you trying https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Configuring+a+Third-Party+Key+Manager?

Comment: Yes..Did you tried this pattern in your project? if so, what is the additional configuration to do.Please share your comments based on your working experience using this pattern.

Comment: When you configure a 3rd party key manager, you have to implement KeyManager interface of APIM. If you follow the doc, it should work.